# Oracle Fast Connection Failover not working for ODP.NET. Getting Connection Request Timeout Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle12c, odp.net

I am using ODP.NET for my MVC project and keep getting "-1000 Connection Request Timeout Error" when the Database goes down and then comes back up again. It starts working as soon as I recycle IIS AppPool. I tried to use ClearAllPool(), ClearPool(connection) inside the catch block to remove the error connection but both didn't work. I found a post on StackOverflow to use Fast Connection Failover by adding HA events=true in the connectionstring. I tried that too but no luck. I asked DBA and they said the feature is ON the server-side by default. I don't know why ODP.NET is still using an old invalid connection created when the database was down even if database is up and running? All of my code is also wrapped inside a using block which will close/dispose connection. My Oracle.DataAccess version is 12.1.0. I read every page on google about the connection pooling, FCF but nothing helped.

my connectionstring is as follow:

```
<add name="XXX"; providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"; connectionString="DataSource=XXX;username=xxx;password=XXX;Pooling=True;Connection Timeout=120; Connection LifeTime=120; Validate Connection=True; Min Pool size=1;Max Pool size=180; HA events=true; Incr Pool size=5; Decr Pool size=2;"/>
```

here is my oracle connection code:

```
using(OracleConnection conn= new OracleConnection(connectionstring))
{
    try
   {
      OracleCommand cmd=new OracleCommand("storedprocedure",conn) 
      {CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure};
      //add parameters to command
        foreach(var parmeter in parameters)
        {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
        conn.Open(); // this is where exception occurs

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
   catch(OracleException ex)
   {
     if(conn.State=ConnectionState.Open)
     {
      conn.Close();
      conn.Dispose();
     }

     //log exception ex in logfile

   }

      if(conn.State=ConnectionState.Open)
      {
       conn.Close();
       conn.Dispose();
      }
}
//Dispose All Parameters using Dispose() outside using statement.
foreach(var parmeter in parameters){
parameter.Dispose();
}
```

The only solution work is when I set Pooling=False, which we don't want to do.

I played with these connectionstring properties like increase Min pool size, increase connection Lifetime etc. but nothing seems to be working.

I will really appreciate any help here.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there an option in your connection pool settings to test the connections (typically with a simple query like "select 1 from dual;") before using them? The HA features you are attempting to use are only valid in an Oracle RAC configuration where you have an alternate instance to fail over to. They won't help in a situation where the database is actually completely down. Dead connections generally must be detected and managed/reset by the connection pool, and if the database is down then they will need to be discarded and reconnected. Connections cannot survive a database restart.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No I don't have setting to test connection before using it. my apologies but how this setting will help?

Comment: Setting the pool to test connections before checking them out to the app ensures that broken ones are identified before the app tries to use them. This is a common feature of most pools. A dead connection to an Oracle DB won't be recognized until you try to use it for something, so it is important for the connection pool to identify the bad ones, discard them, and replace them to maintain the minimum number of viable connections. There are typically settings to enable testing, to specify how often connections are tested, the query for the test, and the min number of connections to maintain.

Comment: If your database is shutdown/restarted, then all of your connections will be broken and must be discarded and replaced. A connection pool with the above features will keep attempting to create the minimum number of required connections until it succeeds, logging back in to the DB automatically as soon as it comes back online. Depending on the length of the outage and the tolerance of your application for delays in obtaining a valid connection thread (and possible interrupted transactions when the DB goes offline), this may allow your app to survive a restart transparently to end users.

Comment: I think this makes perfect sense to me. I will add connection testing in my code and check if it works. Thanks again for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and tell me if you still have this issue

```cs
using(OracleConnection conn= new OracleConnection(connectionstring))
using(OracleCommand cmd=new OracleCommand("storedprocedure",conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    foreach(var parmeter in parameters)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
    conn.Open(); // this is where exception occurs
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

if error is not desired put this entire block into `try/catch`

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution worked for me. I enclosed cmd in a separate using statement as you suggested and it worked. Does this mean the first "using " statement in my previous code doesn't dispose oracle command properly?

Comment: @Dan you've disposed connection but not command. Command holds connection. Your code sequence wasn't optimal. To answer this, you need to reflect the Oracle data access dll. I've done it before and learned a lot.

Comment: I understand it now. thanks a lot for your help. You saved a lot of time. We were trying to find a solution for many days. Actually, today, I found that one of my co-workers is not getting a connection time out error if the database goes down and comes back. He has the same code sequence I have where cmd is not disposed. The only difference we have is He is using Oracle 12.2 and I use 12.1. I don't understand what changed in 12.2 where it is okay if cmd is not disposed correctly. I did some research but didn't find anything. will keep researching. But thanks for your solution. It works great.